# Is past tense + "already" equal to present perfect in a certain case?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

I read a grammar book somewhere which I don't recall the title, and I want to make sure whether I remember it correctly. Are these sentences equivalent?

1. Did you already visit the US?
2. Have you visited the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. "already" suggests something happened earlier than expected, so (1) suggests that the person already visited the US earlier than he/she was supposed to. (2) is just asking in general if he/she visited the US before in her/his entire life.

If you want similar meanings, you can just remove the "already".

Answer (score 2):

They have similar meanings, but there are a couple of differences.

1. "Already" often implies that there is an expectation that the event will occur or has occurred. Also, because no specific time is mentioned, the present perfect would probably work better than the simple past tense. Therefore, sentence 2 would work better in more situations than sentence 1.
2. Sometimes people use the simple past tense in situations for which textbooks recommend the past perfect. For example:

> "When I travelled around the world last year, visiting every English-speaking country, I flew directly from Canada to Ireland."
> "Oh, really? Had you already visited the US?"

That is what most textbooks would recommend, but people might sometimes say "did you already visit the US" with the same meaning. ("Have you visited the US" would have a different meaning.)